# Is it possible to create a list with a sub-list ? Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list

What I am trying to do:

**Heading** LIST with one or more **Sub-Heading** items, each **Sub-Heading** item with one or more **Sub-Sub-Heading** items

Basically what I need is a list inside a list ?

Heading1 --->
*sub-heading1*, sub-heading2, sub-heading3, sub-heading4...

*Sub-Heading1* --->
sub-sub-heading1, sub-sub-heading2, sub-sub-heading3, sub-sub-heading4...

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this via code ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to make multiple lists and use lookup fields/columns. That way you can create the layers you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. You can create your items as a Folder Content Type with the additional fields you need. This way it easy to create elements within a container and easy to retrieve/display, but has problem with deep nesting due to url length.
2. You can have your items contain a lookup field into the list itself for the containing element. This can create hierarchies of any depth, but is a bit harder to create.
3. Use managed metadata